# Springboot actuator not working in OpenShift

Tags: openshift, spring-boot-actuator

I have been struggling with this problem for a few days now. My Springboot application's actuator work locally, but when deploy to OpenShift, it doesn't work.

**application.properties**

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info,health
management.health.probes.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
```

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.7.5'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.7.5'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:2.7.5'
```

With the above configuration, I can run the application locally and hit the endpoints below successfully:
http://localhost:8081/actuator/health/liveness
http://localhost:8081/actuator/health/readiness

**OpenShift Environment Variables:**

```
MANAGEMENT_SECURITY_ENABLED=false
MANAGEMENT_ENDPOINTS_WEB_EXPOSURE_INCLUDE=*
MANAGEMENT_ENDPOINTS_WEB_BASE_PATH=/actuator
MANAGEMENT_HEALTH_PROBES_ENABLED=true
MANAGEMENT_ENDPOINT_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
MANAGEMENT_ENDPOINT_HEALTH_PROBES_ENABLED=true
MANAGEMENT_ENDPOINTS_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT=true
SPRINGDOC_SHOW_ACTUATOR=true
SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXT_PATH=/proxy/bankroute/
```

When the above configuration, the application started up, however, I am not able to get to <htt..>/proxy/bankroute/actuator/
Always get error 404.

**OpenShift Health Checks Configuration:**

```
readinessProbe:
   failureThreshold: 3
   httpGet:
     path: /proxy/bankroute/actuator/health/readiness
     port: 9080
     scheme: HTTP
   initialDelaySeconds: 15
   periodSeconds: 10
   successThreshold: 1
   timeoutSeconds: 1
```

When adding the OpenShift Health Checks Configuration above, the application doesn't start up at all.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you're trying to reach the actuator probe endpoints externally, make sure the deployment provides routes to those (including the nested routes). You could test your understanding of this by creating a [RestController](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) endpoint that returns a hard-coded string like: `{"test":"UP"}`.

Comment: I have a feeling that your routes are specified incorrectly. Probably something to do with the internal vs. external meaning of "/proxy/".

Comment: @BrentBradburn When the application is up, I am able to it other REST endpoints such as /proxy/bankroute/depositTransaction but none related to this path /proxy/bankroute/actuator

Comment: Do the RestConroller implementations for those include `/proxy/` in the path? Your actuator endpoints do. But I suspect they shouldn't (internally).

Comment: @BrentBradburn the path is just spring context:
SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXT_PATH=/proxy/bankroute/